# Tcsh script getting input from user till ctrl-d and output to a file

Tags: unix, input, output, tcsh

I have tried a number of websites for help. This is what I have now. I need to get input in a tcsh script from the user and output to a file till the user clicks ctrl-d

```
> cat > fileName
```

result

> Ambiguous output redirect.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one redirection is required.

```
 cat > fileName
```

will receive data from the stdin and write the data onto the file.